# Dask Dataframe: select rows where hourly values of usage are greater than the daily average

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a dask dataframe of data in the form:

```
index     time          cooling_kwh   total_energy_kwh      building_id
0,    1/1/2020 1:00,    0.0,          10.303025148,         14
1,    1/1/2020 2:00,    0.0,          10.501065738,         14
2,    1/1/2020 3:00,    0.0,          10.580369134999998,   14
3,    1/1/2020 4:00,    0.0,          10.622952277,         14
4,    1/1/2020 5:00,    0.0,          10.784153656,         14
5,    1/1/2020 6:00,    0.0,          11.384857169,         14
6,    1/1/2020 7:00,    0.002205914,  15.601318334,         14
7,    1/1/2020 8:00,    0.000451000,  19.410880241999998,   14
...
```

The rows continue for a whole year and then go on with a year's data for other building ids.
I need to select only the rows where the `total_energy_usage_kwh` value is greater than it's average over the whole day. FYI, this is just a test set of data for a larger set that is already is a dask data frame. I have already created a table with the daily average values:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv('file_name', usecols=[list of cols to use])
dask_raw_data = dd.from_pandas(raw_data, npartitions=n)

d1 = {'time': 'last', 'electricity_cooling_kwh': 'sum', 'total_site_electricity_kwh': 'sum', 'building_id': 'last'}
grouped_by_hour = dask_raw_data.groupby(dask_raw_data.index // 4).agg(d1) #original data is grouped in 15 minute intervals

d2 = {'time': 'first', 'electricity_cooling_kwh': 'sum', 'total_site_electricity_kwh': 'mean', 'building_id': 'last'}\
grouped_by_day = grouped_by_hour.groupby(grouped_by_hour.index // 24).agg(d2)
```

which looks like this:

```
index      time         cooling_kwh             average_ttl_energy_kwh, building_id
0,     1/1/2020 1:00,   0.031805705999999996,   21.467724711749998,     14
1,     1/2/2020 1:00,   0.048682367,            11.29718203445833,      14
2,     1/3/2020 1:00,   0.006180415,            7.5111043845,           14
3,     1/4/2020 1:00,   0.061217776,            21.422023511583333,     14
4,     1/5/2020 1:00,   0.10863825899999999,    21.234984764874998,     14
5,     1/6/2020 1:00,   0.07775508199999999,    21.259932711666664,     14
...
```

and I have also found that to select rows where the hourly usage is greater than a number n I can use:

```
above_average_usage = grouped_by_hour[grouped_by_hour.total_site_electricity_kwh > n]
```

I am unsure how to go about combining these two pieces, I tried:

```
above_average_usage = grouped_by_hour[grouped_by_hour.total_site_electricity_kwh > grouped_by_hour.groupby(grouped_by_hour['time'].dt.date).time.mean().compute()]
```

but the datetime objects are unable to be summed (TypeError: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation sum) and I get the feeling this would not return what I want either way. In the end, I need to sum the values in the cooling_kwh column at times where total_energy_usage_kwh is greater than its average for the day and the data needs to remain grouped by building_id which I solved when I was using a pandas dataframe before attempting dask by:

```
d4 = {'electricity_cooling_kwh': 'sum'}
summed_above_average_hours = above_average_hours.groupby([above_average_hours.building_id, above_average_hours['time'].dt.date]).agg(d4)
```

Comment: Hi AidenFarrar and welcome on SO. Please have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular share a sample of your data and edit your question using code blocks.

Comment: @rpanai I have edited with some reformating, is this more comprehensible?